# Calling function in the constructor C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-store

I have class `CategoryPage`, In  some region Called `navigationHelper_loadState`, there is a function called `clickeditem` with one parameter

```
        public void clickeditem(ItemClickEventArgs Args)
    {
        function = Args.ClickedItem.ToString();
    }
```

function is `public static string function;`

when i try to call `clickeditem` in the constructor,

It needs the parameter `(ItemClickEventArgs Args)` , which when i send to the constructor it becames  Null.
I tried to make another constructor , or just call from another public class but i failed

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Your code simply wont work without `Args` as the method body relies on it. What do expect the method to do in the absence of this parameter?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, so i mean how to call this function in the constructor without passing the parameter expect for this specific function

Comment: This *function* is an event handler. Normally event handlers are not called directly. If you want to execute *same* code, then (to avoid duplicating) this code can be moved into separate *method*, which is called from either event handler or other places.

Answer (score 0):

If a method does not provide a default value for a parameter (either via an overload or specifying it in the parameter list), then the caller *must* provide that value. No exceptions.

In your question, it is not clear what you even expect the `function` field to be set to when the caller does not have an `Args` object to pass. But for the sake of argument, let's say you have *some* `string` value in mind.

Then you should change your code so that it looks more like this:

```
public void clickeditem(ItemClickEventArgs Args)
{
    SetFunctionFieldValue(Args.ClickedItem.ToString());
}

private void SetFunctionFieldValue(string text)
{
    function = text;
}
```

Then you can call the same method from your constructor:

```
public CategoryPage()
{
    SetFunctionFieldValue("some field value");
}
```

Of course, I will note that the actual behavior is trivial: you are just setting a field's value. So it seems to me an alternative could be to simply set the field value in the constructor:

```
public CategoryPage()
{
    function = "some field value";
}
```

Then you can leave the event handler method alone.

If you don't even have a `string` value in mind to assign to the `function` field, then I have no idea what you're actually asking to do. All the `clickeditem()` method does in your example is set that field, so why would you even call it from the constructor if you didn't have a value in mind to set the field to? :)